# HTML5 peer to peer video?

Tags: html, video-streaming, websocket, html5-video, p2p

I am having trouble finding out if W3C has actually specified something for peer to peer voice and video.

There are several old solutions (2011), with several blogs and posts on here saying those solutions are outdated. These include Adobe Cirrus / Stratus in Flash 10+, Ericcson Lab's API, and some say the WebSockets API for HTML5 was not decided on.

Does HTML5 or any non-Adobe technology have P2P video support? Are WebSockets the standard for HTML5 peer-to-peer?

Comment: As far as i know if you want to stream video you need some server to do that streaming, and after you can just use some video file as output to use it in <video>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are talking about webrtc the draft can be found here

[w3c webrtc draft](http://dev.w3.org/2011/webrtc/editor/webrtc.html)

Answer (score 1):

[Bowser](https://labs.ericsson.com/apps/bowser) is the web-browser from Sony Ericson. Which have default embedded WebRTC on it.

[image]

it works with Bowser

- Firefox           (ignoring webRTC as default)
- Chrome            (ignoring webRTC as default)
- Internet Explorer (ignoring webRTC as default)

Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer should stop fighting and embed WebRTC default in all latest versions of there release, as Sony Ericsson already made Bowser to prove it and show it how it works.